# ggplot with 2 y axes on each side and different scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-faq

I need to plot a bar chart showing counts and a line chart showing rate all in one chart, I can do both of them separately, but when I put them together, I scale of the first layer (i.e. the `geom_bar`) is overlapped by the second layer (i.e. the `geom_line`).

Can I move the axis of the `geom_line` to the right?

Comment: Could you use an approach as shwon here, http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2 ?

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917689/how-to-use-facets-with-a-dual-y-axis-ggplot/40746716#40746716)

Comment: scroll way down to see the native ``ggplot2`` implementation within ``scale_y_*``, currently called ``sec.axis``.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Sometimes a client wants two y scales. Giving them the "flawed" speech is often pointless. But I do like the ggplot2 insistence on doing things the right way. I am sure that ggplot is in fact educating the average user about proper visualization techniques.

Maybe you can use faceting and scale free to compare the two data series? - e.g. look here: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Align-two-plots-on-a-page

Comment: I concur with Andreas - sometimes (such as now, for me) a client wants two sets of data on the same plot, and does not want to hear me talk about Plotting Theory.  I either have to convince them to not want that anymore (not always a battle I want to wage), or tell them "the plotting package I'm using doesn't support that."  So I'm switching away from ggplot today for this particular project. =(

Comment: This answer (from the wiki link) is an excellent suggestion, except that both plots are simply labeled "y".  One could just hide the y-axis label and use the facet names for the y-axis, but that seems like a sub-par solution.  Any hints on how to get independent y-axes names for the top and bottom plots?

Comment: why does a plotting package need to insert its own personal opinions into how it operates? No thank you.

Comment: Your link rotted away.  Could you edit your answer and post a summary of what it used to say?

Comment: Cannot agree with this comment (re rant). It is very (!) common to condense information as much as possible, e.g. given the strict restrictions imposed by scientific journals etc., in order to bring across the message quickly. Hence, adding a second y axis is being done anyway, and ggplot should, in my opinion, help in doing so.

Comment: Amazing how unquestioningly words like "flawed" and "right way" are thrown about as if they weren't based on a theory that is itself actually quite opinionated and dogmatic, but is unthinkingly accepted by far too many people, as can be seen by the fact that this completely unhelpful answer (which throws a link-bone) has 72 upvotes at time of writing. 

Whe *comparing* time series, for example, it can be invaluable to have both on the same chart, because correlation of differences is much easier to spot. Just ask the thousands of highly educated finance pros who do this all day every day.

Comment: @hadley I agree. ggplot absolutley 100% needs dual axis.  thousands of people will continue to use dual axis each day and it'd be great to have them in r. its a painful oversight. I am taking data out of r and into excel.

Comment: Several years later.... this issues comes up for me often. In hydrology, we often plot streamflow (left axis) and precipitation (right axis) on the same plot. It's very useful to not have to jump the eyes back and forth between two plots.  Also - in instrumentation I often plot (e.g.) tilt from a tilt sensor on one axis, and temperature on the other, since temperature always affects the tilt reading.

Comment: It's not unheard of in business either, say when you want to plot some loss metric as well as the quantity traded/produced/..., depending on some exogenous parameter.

On top of that, whatever happened to the philosophy of giving users enough rope? Yes, some might use it to hang themselves. Others may well have valid uses for it. I don't feel that a plotting package should outright dictate what kinds of plots you can and cannot create.

Answer (score 203):

Starting with ggplot2 2.2.0 you can add a secondary axis like this (taken from the [ggplot2 2.2.0 announcement](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/09/30/ggplot2-2-2-0-coming-soon/)):

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    "mpg (US)", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 1.20, name = "mpg (UK)")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: The downside is, it only can use some formula transformation of current axes not a new variable, for example.

Comment: But you can transform the new variable so it has about the same range as the old variable and then use sec_axis to display labels that put the new variable back on its original scale.

Answer (score 173):

It's not possible in ggplot2 because I believe plots with separate y scales (not y-scales that are transformations of each other) are fundamentally flawed.  Some problems:

- They are not invertible: given a point on the plot space, you can not uniquely map it back to a point in the data space.
- They are relatively hard to read correctly compared to other options. See [A Study on Dual-Scale Data Charts](https://www.lri.fr/%7Eisenberg/publications/papers/Isenberg_2011_ASO.pdf) by Petra Isenberg, Anastasia Bezerianos, Pierre Dragicevic, and Jean-Daniel Fekete for details.
- They are easily manipulated to mislead: there is no unique way to specify the relative scales of the axes, leaving them open to manipulation.  Two examples from the Junkcharts blog: [one](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/2006/06/illusion_of_suc.html), [two](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/2006/05/the_crossover_l.html)
- They are arbitrary: why have only 2 scales, not 3, 4 or ten?

You also might want to read Stephen Few's lengthy discussion on the topic [Dual-Scaled Axes in Graphs Are They Ever the Best Solution?](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf).

Comment: Would you mind elaborate Your opinion?  Not beeing enlightened , I think its a rather compact way of plotting two independent variables.

It is also a feature that seems to be asked for, and it's beein used widely.

Comment: @hadley: Mostly I agree, but there is a genuine use for multiple y scales - the use of 2 different units for the same data, e.g., Celsius and Fahrenheit scales on temperature time series.

Comment: @Hadley In your opinion. Not in mine, nor many other scientists. Surely this can be achieved by putting a second plot (with a fully transparent background) directly over the first, so they appear as one. I just don't know how to ensure the corners of the bounding boxex are aligned / registered with each other.

Comment: @ADP You are welcome to implement it yourself, but given that I don't believe they're useful, I don't have any plans to.  (Especially given that it's already trivial by rescaling each series independently before plotting)

Comment: @hadley For example, in [Walther-Lieth Climate Diagrams](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Climate_diagrams_system_Walter%2BLieth), two y axes are commonly used. Since there is a fixed prescription how to do that the possible confusion is minimal...

Comment: @hadley I am sorry, I do not see what is problematic with the given climate diagram. Putting temperature and precipitation in one diagram (with the fixed prescription), one gets a quick first guess whether it is humid or arid climate. Or the way around: what would be a better way to visualize temperature, precipitation and their "relation"? Anyway, thanks a lot for your work in ggplot2!

Comment: Sometimes you may only be interested in comparing patterns in which the absolute magnitudes are not important.  In those cases, scaling both variables (`scale(x)`) will allow you to use standard ggplot syntax.

Comment: @hadley I understand the reasons why you are opposed to secondary axes unless they are mere transformations. However, as far as I can tell even mere transformations are not possible if the rescaling is based on a facet variable like in this example: https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-secondary-y-axis-in-ggplot2-with-different-scale-factor-when-using-facet-wrap/64425 Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 108):

There are common use-cases dual y axes, e.g., the [climatograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climograph) showing monthly temperature and precipitation. Here is a simple solution, generalized from Megatron's solution by allowing you to set the lower limit of the variables to something else than zero:

Example data:

```
climate <- tibble(
  Month = 1:12,
  Temp = c(-4,-4,0,5,11,15,16,15,11,6,1,-3),
  Precip = c(49,36,47,41,53,65,81,89,90,84,73,55)
  )
```

Set the following two values to values close to the limits of the data (you can play around with these to adjust the positions of the graphs; the axes will still be correct):

```
ylim.prim <- c(0, 180)   # in this example, precipitation
ylim.sec <- c(-4, 18)    # in this example, temperature
```

The following makes the necessary calculations based on these limits, and makes the plot itself:

```
b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- ylim.prim[1] - b*ylim.sec[1]

ggplot(climate, aes(Month, Precip)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_line(aes(y = a + Temp*b), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Temperature")) +
  scale_x_continuous("Month", breaks = 1:12) +
  ggtitle("Climatogram for Oslo (1961-1990)")
```

[image: Climatogram showing temperature as line and precipitation as barplot]

If you want to make sure that the red line corresponds to the right-hand y axis, you can add a `theme` sentence to the code:

```
ggplot(climate, aes(Month, Precip)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_line(aes(y = a + Temp*b), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Temperature")) +
  scale_x_continuous("Month", breaks = 1:12) +
  theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"), 
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"), 
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red")
        ) +
  ggtitle("Climatogram for Oslo (1961-1990)")
```

which colors the right-hand axis:

[image: Climatogram with red right-hand axis]

Comment: This breaks at some values of `ylim.prim` and `ylim.sec`.

Comment: This is great. Nice example of when two-axis charts are not "flawed". Part of the general tidyverse mentality of thinking they know more about your work than you do.

Comment: When I choose specific axis limits (in my case ylim.prim <- c(90, 130)  and
ylim.sec <- c(15, 30)) it doesn't apply it but chooses arbitrary limits, messing up all the scales. I'm not sure what I'm missing as I copied the above code and just changed variable names and axis limits

Comment: @anke: the text is somewhat sloppy when it refers to ylim.prim and ylim.sec. They don't refer to the limits of the axis, but rather to the limits of your data. When you set ylim.prim <- c(90, 130) and ylim.sec <- c(15, 30) as you mention, the temperature graph ends up high above the bar plot (as the temperature axis starts at -75), but the axes for each graph are still correct.

Comment: @DagHjermann where you typed "there was a bug here" after `ylim.prim[1] - b*ylim.sec[1])`, I believe there shouldn't be a `)` at the end.

Answer (score 70):

You can create a scaling factor which is applied to the second geom and right y-axis. This is derived from Sebastian's solution.

```
library(ggplot2)

scaleFactor <- max(mtcars$cyl) / max(mtcars$hp)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=cyl), method="loess", col="blue") +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=hp * scaleFactor), method="loess", col="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="cyl", sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="hp")) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left=element_text(color="blue"),
    axis.text.y.left=element_text(color="blue"),
    axis.title.y.right=element_text(color="red"),
    axis.text.y.right=element_text(color="red")
  )
```

[image]

Note: using `ggplot2` [v3.0.0](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/)

Comment: This is a clean solution.

Comment: The scaleFactor is the most elegant solution I've seen concerning this secondary axis discussion!

Comment: Extremely (logical) and elegant solution. `2 thumbs up`

Answer (score 66):

Taking above answers and some fine-tuning (and for whatever it's worth), here is a way of achieving two scales via `sec_axis`:

Assume a simple (and purely fictional) data set `dt`: for five days, it tracks the number of interruptions VS productivity:

```
        when numinter prod
1 2018-03-20        1 0.95
2 2018-03-21        5 0.50
3 2018-03-23        4 0.70
4 2018-03-24        3 0.75
5 2018-03-25        4 0.60
```

(the ranges of both columns differ by about factor 5).

The following code will draw both series that they use up the whole y axis:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = dt$when, y = dt$numinter), stat = "identity", fill = "grey") +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = dt$when, y = dt$prod*5), size = 2, color = "blue") + 
  scale_x_date(name = "Day", labels = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Interruptions/day", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./5, name = "Productivity % of best", 
      labels = function(b) { paste0(round(b * 100, 0), "%")})) + 
  theme(
      axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey"),
      axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue"))
```

Here's the result (above code + some color tweaking):

[image: two scales in one ggplot2]

The point (aside from using `sec_axis` when specifying the y_scale is to **multiply** each value the 2nd data series with 5 when specifying the series. In order to get the labels right in the sec_axis definition, it then needs **dividing** by 5 (and formatting). So a crucial part in above code is really `*5` in the geom_line and `~./5` in sec_axis (a formula dividing the current value `.` by 5).

In comparison (I don't want to judge the approaches here), this is how two charts on top of one another look like:

[image: two charts above one another]

You can judge for yourself which one better transports the message (“Don’t disrupt people at work!”). Guess that's a fair way to decide.

The full code for both images (it's not really more than what's above, just complete and ready to run) is here: https://gist.github.com/sebastianrothbucher/de847063f32fdff02c83b75f59c36a7d a more detailed explanation here: https://sebastianrothbucher.github.io/datascience/r/visualization/ggplot/2018/03/24/two-scales-ggplot-r.html

Comment: That's a clever hack to get two different scales with dummy facetting!

I wonder if there is a more "legit" way than using a global variable? It would be nice if a column from the data could be used as input to the `labels` parameter of `scale_y_continuous`?

Answer (score 25):

Here are my two cents on how to do the transformations for secondary axis. First, you want to couple the the ranges of the primary and secondary data. This is usually messy in terms of polluting your global environment with variables you don't want.

To make this easier, we'll make a function factory that produces two functions, wherein `scales::rescale()` does all the heavy lifting. Because these are closures, they are aware of the environment in which they were created, so they 'have a memory' of the `to` and `from` parameters generated before creation.

- One functions does the forward transformation: transforms the secondary data to the primary scale.
- The second function does the reverse transformation: transforms data in primary units to secondary units.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# Function factory for secondary axis transforms
train_sec <- function(primary, secondary, na.rm = TRUE) {
  # Thanks Henry Holm for including the na.rm argument!
  from <- range(secondary, na.rm = na.rm)
  to   <- range(primary, na.rm = na.rm)
  # Forward transform for the data
  forward <- function(x) {
    rescale(x, from = from, to = to)
  }
  # Reverse transform for the secondary axis
  reverse <- function(x) {
    rescale(x, from = to, to = from)
  }
  list(fwd = forward, rev = reverse)
}
```

This seems all rather complicated, but making the function factory makes all the rest easier. Now, before we make a plot, we'll produce the relevant functions by showing the factory the primary and secondary data. We'll use the economics dataset which has very different ranges for the `unemploy` and `psavert` columns.

```r
sec <- with(economics, train_sec(unemploy, psavert))
```

Then we use `y = sec$fwd(psavert)` to rescale the secondary data to primary axis, and specify `~ sec$rev(.)` as the transformation argument to the secondary axis. This gives us a plot where the primary and secondary ranges occupy the same space on the plot.

```r
ggplot(economics, aes(date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = unemploy), colour = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = sec$fwd(psavert)), colour = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~sec$rev(.), name = "psavert"))
```

[image]

The factory is slightly more flexible than that, because if you simply want to rescale the maximum, you can pass in data that has the lower limit at 0.

```r
# Rescaling the maximum
sec <- with(economics, train_sec(c(0, max(unemploy)),
                                 c(0, max(psavert))))

ggplot(economics, aes(date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = unemploy), colour = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = sec$fwd(psavert)), colour = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~sec$rev(.), name = "psavert"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I admit the difference in this example is not that very obvious, but if you look closely you can see that the maxima are the same and the red line goes lower than the blue one.

EDIT:

This approach has now been captured and expanded in the [`help_secondary()`](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/reference/help_secondary.html#examples) function in the ggh4x package. Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x.

Comment: This was a great solution - only thing I would add is "rm.na = TRUE" on those range functions in case the data being plotted has some NA values

Comment: That's a good suggestion thanks! I included it in the answer above

Comment: @HenryHolm how did you remove NA values for the second axis?  I am getting `! transformation for secondary axes must be monotonic` because of this I think.

Comment: This deserves to be higher on the list - it's a deceptively simple and elegant approach to the problem without resorting to ugly hacks, for those 0.1% of cases where dual axes are actually a good idea.

Answer (score 14):

The technical backbone to the solution of this challenge has been provided by *Kohske* some 3 years ago [[KOHSKE](https://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2)]. The topic and the technicalities around its solution have been discussed on several instances here on Stackoverflow [IDs: 18989001, 29235405, 21026598]. So i shall only provide a specific variation and some explanatory walkthrough, using above solutions.

Let us assume we do have some data *y1* in group *G1* to which some data *y2* in group *G2* is related in some way, e.g. range/scale transformed or with some noise added. So one wants to plot the data together on one plot with the scale of *y1* on the left and *y2* on the right.

```
  df <- data.frame(item=LETTERS[1:n],  y1=c(-0.8684, 4.2242, -0.3181, 0.5797, -0.4875), y2=c(-5.719, 205.184, 4.781, 41.952, 9.911 )) # made up!

> df
  item      y1         y2
1    A -0.8684 -19.154567
2    B  4.2242 219.092499
3    C -0.3181  18.849686
4    D  0.5797  46.945161
5    E -0.4875  -4.721973
```

If we now plot our data together with something like

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(label=item)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_segment(aes(x='G1', xend='G2', y=y1, yend=y2), color='grey')+
  geom_text(aes(x='G1', y=y1), color='blue') +
  geom_text(aes(x='G2', y=y2), color='red') +
  theme(legend.position='none', panel.grid=element_blank())
```

it doesnt align nicely as the smaller scale *y1* obviosuly gets collapsed by larger scale *y2*.

**The trick here to meet the challenge is to techncially plot *both* data sets against the first scale *y1* but report the second against a secondary axis with labels showing the original scale *y2*.**

So we build a first helper function *CalcFudgeAxis* which calculates and collects features of the new axis to be shown. The function can be amended to ayones liking (this one just maps *y2* onto the range of *y1*).

```
CalcFudgeAxis = function( y1, y2=y1) {
  Cast2To1 = function(x) ((ylim1[2]-ylim1[1])/(ylim2[2]-ylim2[1])*x) # x gets mapped to range of ylim2
  ylim1 <- c(min(y1),max(y1))
  ylim2 <- c(min(y2),max(y2))    
  yf <- Cast2To1(y2)
  labelsyf <- pretty(y2)  
  return(list(
    yf=yf,
    labels=labelsyf,
    breaks=Cast2To1(labelsyf)
  ))
}
```

what yields some:

```
> FudgeAxis <- CalcFudgeAxis( df$y1, df$y2 )

> FudgeAxis
$yf
[1] -0.4094344  4.6831656  0.4029175  1.0034664 -0.1009335

$labels
[1] -50   0  50 100 150 200 250

$breaks
[1] -1.068764  0.000000  1.068764  2.137529  3.206293  4.275058  5.343822


> cbind(df, FudgeAxis$yf)
  item      y1         y2 FudgeAxis$yf
1    A -0.8684 -19.154567   -0.4094344
2    B  4.2242 219.092499    4.6831656
3    C -0.3181  18.849686    0.4029175
4    D  0.5797  46.945161    1.0034664
5    E -0.4875  -4.721973   -0.1009335
```

Now I wraped *Kohske's* solution in the second helper function *PlotWithFudgeAxis*  (into which we throw the ggplot object and helper object of the new axis):

```
library(gtable)
library(grid)

PlotWithFudgeAxis = function( plot1, FudgeAxis) {
  # based on: https://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2
  plot2 <- plot1 + with(FudgeAxis, scale_y_continuous( breaks=breaks, labels=labels))

  #extract gtable
  g1<-ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(plot1))
  g2<-ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(plot2))

  #overlap the panel of the 2nd plot on that of the 1st plot
  pp<-c(subset(g1$layout, name=="panel", se=t:r))
  g<-gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name=="panel")]], pp$t, pp$l, pp$b,pp$l)

  ia <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-l")
  ga <- g2$grobs[[ia]]
  ax <- ga$children[[2]]
  ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths)
  ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)
  ax$grobs[[1]]$x <- ax$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + unit(0.15, "cm")
  g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1)
  g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)

  grid.draw(g)
}
```

Now all can be put together: **Below code shows, how the proposed solution could be used in a day-to-day environment**. The plot call now doesnt plot the original data *y2* anymore but a cloned version *yf* (held inside the pre-calculated helper object *FudgeAxis*), which runs of the scale of *y1*. The original ggplot objet is then manipulated with *Kohske's* helper function *PlotWithFudgeAxis* to add a second axis preserving the scales of *y2*. It plots as well the manipulated plot.

```
FudgeAxis <- CalcFudgeAxis( df$y1, df$y2 )

tmpPlot <- ggplot(data=df, aes(label=item)) +
      theme_bw() + 
      geom_segment(aes(x='G1', xend='G2', y=y1, yend=FudgeAxis$yf), color='grey')+
      geom_text(aes(x='G1', y=y1), color='blue') +
      geom_text(aes(x='G2', y=FudgeAxis$yf), color='red') +
      theme(legend.position='none', panel.grid=element_blank())

PlotWithFudgeAxis(tmpPlot, FudgeAxis)
```

**This now plots as desired with two axis, *y1* on the left and *y2* on the right**

[image: 2 axes]

Above solution is, to put it straight, a limited shaky hack. As it plays with the ggplot kernel it will throw some warnings that we exchange post-the-fact scales, etc. It has to be handled with care and may produce some undesired behaviour in another setting. As well one may need to fiddle around with the helper functions to get the layout as desired. The placement of the legend is such an issue (it would be placed between the panel and the new axis; this is why I droped it). The scaling / alignment of the 2 axis is as well a bit challenging: The code above works nicely when both scales contain the "0", else one axis gets shifted. So definetly with some opportunities to improve...

In case on wants to save the pic one has to wrap the call into device open / close:

```
png(...)
PlotWithFudgeAxis(tmpPlot, FudgeAxis)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 10):

The following article helped me to combine two plots generated by ggplot2 on a single row:

[Multiple graphs on one page (ggplot2) by Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/)

And here is what the code may look like in this case:

```
p1 <- 
  ggplot() + aes(mns)+ geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth=0.01, colour="black", fill="white") + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(mns, na.rm=T)), color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1) +  geom_density(alpha=.2)

p2 <- 
  ggplot() + aes(mns)+ geom_histogram( binwidth=0.01, colour="black", fill="white") + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(mns, na.rm=T)), color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1)  

multiplot(p1,p2,cols=2)
```

Comment: What happened to the multiplot function? I get an error that the function could not be found, despite of the fact that i have ggplot2 library installled and loaded.

Comment: @Danka The multiplot function is a custom function (at the bottom of the linked page).

Comment: Can you add the plot?

Comment: Recently, there are many packages that has more options/features than `multiplot` https://stackoverflow.com/a/51220506/

Answer (score 7):

For me the tricky part was figuring out the transformation function between the two axis. I used [myCurveFit](https://www.mycurvefit.com/) for that.

```
> dput(combined_80_8192 %>% filter (time > 270, time < 280))
structure(list(run = c(268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 
268L, 268L, 268L, 263L, 263L, 263L, 263L, 263L, 263L, 263L, 263L, 
263L, 263L, 269L, 269L, 269L, 269L, 269L, 269L, 269L, 269L, 269L, 
269L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 
267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 265L, 
265L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 266L, 266L, 
266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 262L, 262L, 262L, 
262L, 262L, 262L, 262L, 262L, 262L, 262L, 264L, 264L, 264L, 264L, 
264L, 264L, 264L, 264L, 264L, 264L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 
260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L), repetition = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), module = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "scenario.node[0].nicVLCTail.phyVLC", class = "factor"), 
    configname = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Road-Vlc", class = "factor"), packetByteLength = c(8192L, 
    8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 
    8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 
    8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 
    8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 
    8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 
    8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 
    8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 
    8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 
    8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 
    8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 
    8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L, 8192L
    ), numVehicles = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), dDistance = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L), time = c(270.166006903445, 
    271.173853699836, 272.175873251122, 273.177524313334, 274.182946177105, 
    275.188959464989, 276.189675339937, 277.198250244799, 278.204619457189, 
    279.212562800009, 270.164199199177, 271.168527215152, 272.173072994958, 
    273.179210429715, 274.184351047337, 275.18980754378, 276.194816792995, 
    277.198598277809, 278.202398083519, 279.210634593917, 270.210674322891, 
    271.212395107473, 272.218871923292, 273.219060500457, 274.220486359614, 
    275.22401452372, 276.229646658839, 277.231060448138, 278.240407241942, 
    279.2437126347, 270.283554249858, 271.293168593832, 272.298574288769, 
    273.304413221348, 274.306272082517, 275.309023049011, 276.317805897347, 
    277.324403550028, 278.332855848701, 279.334046374594, 270.118608539613, 
    271.127947700074, 272.133887145863, 273.135726000491, 274.135994529981, 
    275.136563912708, 276.140120735361, 277.144298344151, 278.146885137621, 
    279.147552358659, 270.206015567272, 271.214618077209, 272.216566814903, 
    273.225435592582, 274.234014573683, 275.242949179958, 276.248417809711, 
    277.248800670023, 278.249750333404, 279.252926560188, 270.217182684494, 
    271.218357511397, 272.224698488895, 273.231112784327, 274.238740508457, 
    275.242715184122, 276.249053562718, 277.250325509798, 278.258488063493, 
    279.261141590137, 270.282904173953, 271.284689544638, 272.294220723234, 
    273.299749415592, 274.30628880553, 275.312075103126, 276.31579134717, 
    277.321905523606, 278.326305136748, 279.333056502253, 270.258991527456, 
    271.260224091407, 272.270076810133, 273.27052037648, 274.274119348094, 
    275.280808254502, 276.286353887245, 277.287064312339, 278.294444793276, 
    279.296772014594, 270.333066283904, 271.33877455992, 272.345842319903, 
    273.350858180493, 274.353972278505, 275.360454510107, 276.365088896161, 
    277.369166956941, 278.372571708911, 279.38017503079), distanceToTx = c(80.255266401689, 
    80.156059067023, 79.98823695539, 79.826647129071, 79.76678667135, 
    79.788239825292, 79.734539327997, 79.74766421514, 79.801243848241, 
    79.765920888341, 80.255266401689, 80.15850240049, 79.98823695539, 
    79.826647129071, 79.76678667135, 79.788239825292, 79.735078924078, 
    79.74766421514, 79.801243848241, 79.764622734914, 80.251248121732, 
    80.146436869316, 79.984682320466, 79.82292012342, 79.761908518748, 
    79.796988776281, 79.736920997657, 79.745038376718, 79.802638836686, 
    79.770029970452, 80.243475525691, 80.127918207499, 79.978303140866, 
    79.816259117883, 79.749322030693, 79.809916018889, 79.744456560867, 
    79.738655068783, 79.788697533211, 79.784288359619, 80.260412958482, 
    80.168426829066, 79.992034911214, 79.830845773284, 79.7756751763, 
    79.778156038931, 79.732399593756, 79.752769548846, 79.799967731078, 
    79.757585110481, 80.251248121732, 80.146436869316, 79.984682320466, 
    79.822062073459, 79.75884601899, 79.801590491435, 79.738335109094, 
    79.74347007248, 79.803215965043, 79.771471198955, 80.250257298678, 
    80.146436869316, 79.983831684476, 79.822062073459, 79.75884601899, 
    79.801590491435, 79.738335109094, 79.74347007248, 79.803849157574, 
    79.771471198955, 80.243475525691, 80.130180105198, 79.978303140866, 
    79.816881283718, 79.749322030693, 79.80984572883, 79.744456560867, 
    79.738655068783, 79.790548644175, 79.784288359619, 80.246349000313, 
    80.137056554491, 79.980581246037, 79.818924707937, 79.753176142361, 
    79.808777040341, 79.741609845588, 79.740770913572, 79.796316397253, 
    79.777593733292, 80.238796415443, 80.119021911134, 79.974810568944, 
    79.814065350562, 79.743657315504, 79.810146783217, 79.749945098869, 
    79.737122584544, 79.781650522348, 79.791554933936), headerNoError = c(0.99999999989702, 
    0.9999999999981, 0.99999999999946, 0.9999999928026, 0.99999873265475, 
    0.77080141574964, 0.99007491438593, 0.99994396605059, 0.45588747062284, 
    0.93484381262491, 0.99999999989702, 0.99999999999816, 0.99999999999946, 
    0.9999999928026, 0.99999873265475, 0.77080141574964, 0.99008458785106, 
    0.99994396605059, 0.45588747062284, 0.93480223051707, 0.99999999989735, 
    0.99999999999789, 0.99999999999946, 0.99999999287551, 0.99999876302649, 
    0.46903147501117, 0.98835168988253, 0.99994427085086, 0.45235035271542, 
    0.93496741877335, 0.99999999989803, 0.99999999999781, 0.99999999999948, 
    0.99999999318224, 0.99994254156311, 0.46891362282273, 0.93382613917348, 
    0.99994594904099, 0.93002915596843, 0.93569767251247, 0.99999999989658, 
    0.99999999998074, 0.99999999999946, 0.99999999272802, 0.99999871586781, 
    0.76935240919896, 0.99002587758346, 0.99999881589732, 0.46179415706093, 
    0.93417422376389, 0.99999999989735, 0.99999999999789, 0.99999999999946, 
    0.99999999289347, 0.99999876940486, 0.46930769326427, 0.98837353639905, 
    0.99994447154714, 0.16313586712094, 0.93500824170148, 0.99999999989744, 
    0.99999999999789, 0.99999999999946, 0.99999999289347, 0.99999876940486, 
    0.46930769326427, 0.98837353639905, 0.99994447154714, 0.16330039178981, 
    0.93500824170148, 0.99999999989803, 0.99999999999781, 0.99999999999948, 
    0.99999999316541, 0.99994254156311, 0.46794586553266, 0.93382613917348, 
    0.99994594904099, 0.9303627789484, 0.93569767251247, 0.99999999989778, 
    0.9999999999978, 0.99999999999948, 0.99999999311433, 0.99999878195152, 
    0.47101897739483, 0.93368891853679, 0.99994556595217, 0.7571113417265, 
    0.93553999975802, 0.99999999998191, 0.99999999999784, 0.99999999999971, 
    0.99999891129658, 0.99994309267792, 0.46510628979591, 0.93442584181035, 
    0.99894450514543, 0.99890078483692, 0.76933812306423), receivedPower_dbm = c(-93.023492290586, 
    -92.388378035287, -92.205716340607, -93.816400586752, -95.023489422885, 
    -100.86308557253, -98.464763536915, -96.175707680373, -102.06189538385, 
    -99.716653422746, -93.023492290586, -92.384760627397, -92.205716340607, 
    -93.816400586752, -95.023489422885, -100.86308557253, -98.464201120719, 
    -96.175707680373, -102.06189538385, -99.717150021506, -93.022927803442, 
    -92.404017215549, -92.204561341714, -93.814319484729, -95.016990717792, 
    -102.01669022332, -98.558088145955, -96.173817001483, -102.07406915124, 
    -99.71517574876, -93.021813165972, -92.409586309743, -92.20229160243, 
    -93.805335867418, -96.184419849593, -102.01709540787, -99.728735187547, 
    -96.163233028048, -99.772547164798, -99.706399753853, -93.024204617071, 
    -92.745813384859, -92.206884754512, -93.818508150122, -95.027018807793, 
    -100.87000577258, -98.467607232407, -95.005311380324, -102.04157607608, 
    -99.724619517, -93.022927803442, -92.404017215549, -92.204561341714, 
    -93.813803344588, -95.015606885523, -102.0157405687, -98.556982278361, 
    -96.172566862738, -103.21871579865, -99.714687230796, -93.022787428238, 
    -92.404017215549, -92.204274688493, -93.813803344588, -95.015606885523, 
    -102.0157405687, -98.556982278361, -96.172566862738, -103.21784988098, 
    -99.714687230796, -93.021813165972, -92.409950613665, -92.20229160243, 
    -93.805838770576, -96.184419849593, -102.02042267497, -99.728735187547, 
    -96.163233028048, -99.768774335378, -99.706399753853, -93.022228914406, 
    -92.411048503835, -92.203136463155, -93.807357409082, -95.012865008237, 
    -102.00985717796, -99.730352912911, -96.165675535906, -100.92744056572, 
    -99.708301333236, -92.735781110993, -92.408137395049, -92.119533319039, 
    -94.982938427575, -96.181073124017, -102.03018610927, -99.721633629806, 
    -97.32940323644, -97.347613268692, -100.87007386786), snr = c(49.848348091678, 
    57.698190927109, 60.17669971462, 41.529809724535, 31.452202106925, 
    8.1976890851341, 14.240447804094, 24.122884195464, 6.2202875499406, 
    10.674183333671, 49.848348091678, 57.746270018264, 60.17669971462, 
    41.529809724535, 31.452202106925, 8.1976890851341, 14.242292077376, 
    24.122884195464, 6.2202875499406, 10.672962852322, 49.854827699773, 
    57.49079026127, 60.192705735317, 41.549715223147, 31.499301851462, 
    6.2853718719014, 13.937702343688, 24.133388256416, 6.2028757927148, 
    10.677815810561, 49.867624820879, 57.417115267867, 60.224172277442, 
    41.635752021705, 24.074540962859, 6.2847854917092, 10.644529778044, 
    24.19227425387, 10.537686730745, 10.699414795917, 49.84017267426, 
    53.139646558768, 60.160512118809, 41.509660845114, 31.42665220053, 
    8.1846370024428, 14.231126423354, 31.584125885363, 6.2494585568733, 
    10.654622041348, 49.854827699773, 57.49079026127, 60.192705735317, 
    41.55465351989, 31.509340361646, 6.2867464196657, 13.941251828322, 
    24.140336174865, 4.765718874642, 10.679016976694, 49.856439162736, 
    57.49079026127, 60.196678846453, 41.55465351989, 31.509340361646, 
    6.2867464196657, 13.941251828322, 24.140336174865, 4.7666691818074, 
    10.679016976694, 49.867624820879, 57.412299088098, 60.224172277442, 
    41.630930975211, 24.074540962859, 6.279972363168, 10.644529778044, 
    24.19227425387, 10.546845071479, 10.699414795917, 49.862851240855, 
    57.397787176282, 60.212457625018, 41.61637603957, 31.529239767749, 
    6.2952688513108, 10.640565481982, 24.178672145334, 8.0771089950663, 
    10.694731030907, 53.262541905639, 57.43627424514, 61.382796189332, 
    31.747253311549, 24.093100244121, 6.2658701281075, 10.661949889074, 
    18.495227442305, 18.417839037171, 8.1845086722809), frameId = c(15051, 
    15106, 15165, 15220, 15279, 15330, 15385, 15452, 15511, 15566, 
    15019, 15074, 15129, 15184, 15239, 15298, 15353, 15412, 15471, 
    15526, 14947, 14994, 15057, 15112, 15171, 15226, 15281, 15332, 
    15391, 15442, 14971, 15030, 15085, 15144, 15203, 15262, 15321, 
    15380, 15435, 15490, 14915, 14978, 15033, 15092, 15147, 15198, 
    15257, 15312, 15371, 15430, 14975, 15034, 15089, 15140, 15195, 
    15254, 15313, 15368, 15427, 15478, 14987, 15046, 15105, 15160, 
    15215, 15274, 15329, 15384, 15447, 15506, 14943, 15002, 15061, 
    15116, 15171, 15230, 15285, 15344, 15399, 15454, 14971, 15026, 
    15081, 15136, 15195, 15258, 15313, 15368, 15423, 15478, 15039, 
    15094, 15149, 15204, 15263, 15314, 15369, 15428, 15487, 15546
    ), packetOkSinr = c(0.99999999314881, 0.9999999998736, 0.99999999996428, 
    0.99999952114066, 0.99991568416005, 3.00628034688444e-08, 
    0.51497487795954, 0.99627877136019, 0, 0.011303253101957, 
    0.99999999314881, 0.99999999987726, 0.99999999996428, 0.99999952114066, 
    0.99991568416005, 3.00628034688444e-08, 0.51530974419663, 
    0.99627877136019, 0, 0.011269851265775, 0.9999999931708, 
    0.99999999985986, 0.99999999996428, 0.99999952599145, 0.99991770469509, 
    0, 0.45861812482641, 0.99629897628155, 0, 0.011403119534097, 
    0.99999999321568, 0.99999999985437, 0.99999999996519, 0.99999954639936, 
    0.99618434878558, 0, 0.010513119213425, 0.99641022914441, 
    0.00801687746446111, 0.012011103529927, 0.9999999931195, 
    0.99999999871861, 0.99999999996428, 0.99999951617905, 0.99991456738049, 
    2.6525298291169e-08, 0.51328066587104, 0.9999212220316, 0, 
    0.010777054258914, 0.9999999931708, 0.99999999985986, 0.99999999996428, 
    0.99999952718674, 0.99991812902805, 0, 0.45929307038653, 
    0.99631228046814, 0, 0.011436292559188, 0.99999999317629, 
    0.99999999985986, 0.99999999996428, 0.99999952718674, 0.99991812902805, 
    0, 0.45929307038653, 0.99631228046814, 0, 0.011436292559188, 
    0.99999999321568, 0.99999999985437, 0.99999999996519, 0.99999954527918, 
    0.99618434878558, 0, 0.010513119213425, 0.99641022914441, 
    0.00821047996950475, 0.012011103529927, 0.99999999319919, 
    0.99999999985345, 0.99999999996519, 0.99999954188106, 0.99991896371849, 
    0, 0.010410830482692, 0.996384831822, 9.12484388049251e-09, 
    0.011877185067536, 0.99999999879646, 0.9999999998562, 0.99999999998077, 
    0.99992756868677, 0.9962208785486, 0, 0.010971897073662, 
    0.93214999078663, 0.92943956665979, 2.64925478221656e-08), 
    snir = c(49.848348091678, 57.698190927109, 60.17669971462, 
    41.529809724535, 31.452202106925, 8.1976890851341, 14.240447804094, 
    24.122884195464, 6.2202875499406, 10.674183333671, 49.848348091678, 
    57.746270018264, 60.17669971462, 41.529809724535, 31.452202106925, 
    8.1976890851341, 14.242292077376, 24.122884195464, 6.2202875499406, 
    10.672962852322, 49.854827699773, 57.49079026127, 60.192705735317, 
    41.549715223147, 31.499301851462, 6.2853718719014, 13.937702343688, 
    24.133388256416, 6.2028757927148, 10.677815810561, 49.867624820879, 
    57.417115267867, 60.224172277442, 41.635752021705, 24.074540962859, 
    6.2847854917092, 10.644529778044, 24.19227425387, 10.537686730745, 
    10.699414795917, 49.84017267426, 53.139646558768, 60.160512118809, 
    41.509660845114, 31.42665220053, 8.1846370024428, 14.231126423354, 
    31.584125885363, 6.2494585568733, 10.654622041348, 49.854827699773, 
    57.49079026127, 60.192705735317, 41.55465351989, 31.509340361646, 
    6.2867464196657, 13.941251828322, 24.140336174865, 4.765718874642, 
    10.679016976694, 49.856439162736, 57.49079026127, 60.196678846453, 
    41.55465351989, 31.509340361646, 6.2867464196657, 13.941251828322, 
    24.140336174865, 4.7666691818074, 10.679016976694, 49.867624820879, 
    57.412299088098, 60.224172277442, 41.630930975211, 24.074540962859, 
    6.279972363168, 10.644529778044, 24.19227425387, 10.546845071479, 
    10.699414795917, 49.862851240855, 57.397787176282, 60.212457625018, 
    41.61637603957, 31.529239767749, 6.2952688513108, 10.640565481982, 
    24.178672145334, 8.0771089950663, 10.694731030907, 53.262541905639, 
    57.43627424514, 61.382796189332, 31.747253311549, 24.093100244121, 
    6.2658701281075, 10.661949889074, 18.495227442305, 18.417839037171, 
    8.1845086722809), ookSnirBer = c(8.8808636558081e-24, 3.2219795637026e-27, 
    2.6468895519653e-28, 3.9807779074715e-20, 1.0849324265615e-15, 
    2.5705217057696e-05, 4.7313805615763e-08, 1.8800438086075e-12, 
    0.00021005320203921, 1.9147343768384e-06, 8.8808636558081e-24, 
    3.0694773489537e-27, 2.6468895519653e-28, 3.9807779074715e-20, 
    1.0849324265615e-15, 2.5705217057696e-05, 4.7223753038869e-08, 
    1.8800438086075e-12, 0.00021005320203921, 1.9171738578051e-06, 
    8.8229427230445e-24, 3.9715925056443e-27, 2.6045198111088e-28, 
    3.9014083702734e-20, 1.0342658440386e-15, 0.00019591630514278, 
    6.4692014108683e-08, 1.8600094209271e-12, 0.0002140067535655, 
    1.9074922485477e-06, 8.7096574467175e-24, 4.2779443633862e-27, 
    2.5231916788231e-28, 3.5761615214425e-20, 1.9750692814982e-12, 
    0.0001960392878411, 1.9748966344895e-06, 1.7515881895994e-12, 
    2.2078334799411e-06, 1.8649940680806e-06, 8.954486301678e-24, 
    3.2021085732779e-25, 2.690441113724e-28, 4.0627628846548e-20, 
    1.1134484878561e-15, 2.6061691733331e-05, 4.777159157954e-08, 
    9.4891388749738e-16, 0.00020359398491544, 1.9542110660398e-06, 
    8.8229427230445e-24, 3.9715925056443e-27, 2.6045198111088e-28, 
    3.8819641115984e-20, 1.0237769828158e-15, 0.00019562832342849, 
    6.4455095380046e-08, 1.8468752030971e-12, 0.0010099091367628, 
    1.9051035165106e-06, 8.8085966897635e-24, 3.9715925056443e-27, 
    2.594108048185e-28, 3.8819641115984e-20, 1.0237769828158e-15, 
    0.00019562832342849, 6.4455095380046e-08, 1.8468752030971e-12, 
    0.0010088638355194, 1.9051035165106e-06, 8.7096574467175e-24, 
    4.2987746909572e-27, 2.5231916788231e-28, 3.593647329558e-20, 
    1.9750692814982e-12, 0.00019705170257492, 1.9748966344895e-06, 
    1.7515881895994e-12, 2.1868296425817e-06, 1.8649940680806e-06, 
    8.7517439682173e-24, 4.3621551072316e-27, 2.553168170837e-28, 
    3.6469582463164e-20, 1.0032983660212e-15, 0.00019385229409318, 
    1.9830820164805e-06, 1.7760568361323e-12, 2.919419915209e-05, 
    1.8741284335866e-06, 2.8285944348148e-25, 4.1960751547207e-27, 
    7.8468215407139e-29, 8.0407329049747e-16, 1.9380328071065e-12, 
    0.00020004849911333, 1.9393279417733e-06, 5.9354475879597e-10, 
    6.4258355913627e-10, 2.6065221215415e-05), ookSnrBer = c(8.8808636558081e-24, 
    3.2219795637026e-27, 2.6468895519653e-28, 3.9807779074715e-20, 
    1.0849324265615e-15, 2.5705217057696e-05, 4.7313805615763e-08, 
    1.8800438086075e-12, 0.00021005320203921, 1.9147343768384e-06, 
    8.8808636558081e-24, 3.0694773489537e-27, 2.6468895519653e-28, 
    3.9807779074715e-20, 1.0849324265615e-15, 2.5705217057696e-05, 
    4.7223753038869e-08, 1.8800438086075e-12, 0.00021005320203921, 
    1.9171738578051e-06, 8.8229427230445e-24, 3.9715925056443e-27, 
    2.6045198111088e-28, 3.9014083702734e-20, 1.0342658440386e-15, 
    0.00019591630514278, 6.4692014108683e-08, 1.8600094209271e-12, 
    0.0002140067535655, 1.9074922485477e-06, 8.7096574467175e-24, 
    4.2779443633862e-27, 2.5231916788231e-28, 3.5761615214425e-20, 
    1.9750692814982e-12, 0.0001960392878411, 1.9748966344895e-06, 
    1.7515881895994e-12, 2.2078334799411e-06, 1.8649940680806e-06, 
    8.954486301678e-24, 3.2021085732779e-25, 2.690441113724e-28, 
    4.0627628846548e-20, 1.1134484878561e-15, 2.6061691733331e-05, 
    4.777159157954e-08, 9.4891388749738e-16, 0.00020359398491544, 
    1.9542110660398e-06, 8.8229427230445e-24, 3.9715925056443e-27, 
    2.6045198111088e-28, 3.8819641115984e-20, 1.0237769828158e-15, 
    0.00019562832342849, 6.4455095380046e-08, 1.8468752030971e-12, 
    0.0010099091367628, 1.9051035165106e-06, 8.8085966897635e-24, 
    3.9715925056443e-27, 2.594108048185e-28, 3.8819641115984e-20, 
    1.0237769828158e-15, 0.00019562832342849, 6.4455095380046e-08, 
    1.8468752030971e-12, 0.0010088638355194, 1.9051035165106e-06, 
    8.7096574467175e-24, 4.2987746909572e-27, 2.5231916788231e-28, 
    3.593647329558e-20, 1.9750692814982e-12, 0.00019705170257492, 
    1.9748966344895e-06, 1.7515881895994e-12, 2.1868296425817e-06, 
    1.8649940680806e-06, 8.7517439682173e-24, 4.3621551072316e-27, 
    2.553168170837e-28, 3.6469582463164e-20, 1.0032983660212e-15, 
    0.00019385229409318, 1.9830820164805e-06, 1.7760568361323e-12, 
    2.919419915209e-05, 1.8741284335866e-06, 2.8285944348148e-25, 
    4.1960751547207e-27, 7.8468215407139e-29, 8.0407329049747e-16, 
    1.9380328071065e-12, 0.00020004849911333, 1.9393279417733e-06, 
    5.9354475879597e-10, 6.4258355913627e-10, 2.6065221215415e-05
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L), .Names = c("run", 
"repetition", "module", "configname", "packetByteLength", "numVehicles", 
"dDistance", "time", "distanceToTx", "headerNoError", "receivedPower_dbm", 
"snr", "frameId", "packetOkSinr", "snir", "ookSnirBer", "ookSnrBer"
))
```

---

**Finding the transformation function**

1. *y1 --> y2*
   This function is used to transform the data of the secondary y axis to be "normalized" according to the first y axis

[image]

transformation function: `f(y1) = 0.025*x + 2.75`

---

2. *y2 --> y1*
   This function is used to transform the break points of the first y axis to the values of the second y axis. Note that the axis are swapped now.

[image]

transformation function: `f(y1) = 40*x - 110`

---

**Plotting**

Note how the transformation functions are used in the `ggplot` call to transform the data "on-the-fly"

```
ggplot(data=combined_80_8192 %>% filter (time > 270, time < 280), aes(x=time) ) +
  stat_summary(aes(y=receivedPower_dbm ), fun.y=mean, geom="line", colour="black") +
  stat_summary(aes(y=packetOkSinr*40 - 110 ), fun.y=mean, geom="line", colour="black", position = position_dodge(width=10)) +
  scale_x_continuous() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-0,-110,-10), "y_first", sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*0.025+2.75, name="y_second") )
```

The first `stat_summary` call is the one that sets the base for the first y axis.
The second `stat_summary` call is called  to transform the data. Remember that all of the data will take as base the first y axis. So that data needs to be normalized for the first y axis. To do that I use the transformation function on the data: `y=packetOkSinr*40 - 110`

Now to transform the second axis I use the opposite function within the `scale_y_continuous` call: `sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*0.025+2.75, name="y_second")`.

[image]

Comment: R can do this sort of thing, `coef(lm(c(-70, -110) ~ c(1,0)))` and `coef(lm(c(1,0) ~ c(-70, -110)))`. You could define a helper function such as  `equationise <- function(range = c(-70, -110), target = c(1,0)){
  c = coef(lm(target ~ range))  
  as.formula(substitute(~ a*. + b, list(a=c[[2]], b=c[[1]])))
}`

Comment: yeap, I know... just thought the site would be more intuitive

Answer (score 7):

**There's always a way.**

Here's a solution that allows for totally arbitrary axes without rescaling. The idea is to generate two plots, identical except for the axis, and hacking them together using the `insert_yaxis_grob` and `get_y_axis` functions in the `cowplot` package.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

## first plot 
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(disp,hp,color=as.factor(am))) + 
    geom_point() + theme_bw() + theme(legend.position='top', text=element_text(size=16)) +
    ylab("Horse points" )+ xlab("Display size") + scale_color_discrete(name='Transmitter') +
    stat_smooth(se=F)

## same plot with different, arbitrary scale   
p2 <- p1 +
    scale_y_continuous(position='right',breaks=seq(120,173,length.out = 3),
                       labels=c('little','medium little','medium hefty'))

ggdraw(insert_yaxis_grob(p1,get_y_axis(p2,position='right')))
```

[image: taboo plot with two axes]

Answer (score 4):

We definitely could build a plot with dual Y-axises using base R funtion `plot`.

```
# pseudo dataset
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 1000, 1), y1 = sample.int(100, 1000, replace=T), y2 = sample(50, 1000, replace = T))

# plot first plot 
with(df, plot(y1 ~ x, col = "red"))

# set new plot
par(new = T) 

# plot second plot, but without axis
with(df, plot(y2 ~ x, type = "l", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = ""))

# define y-axis and put y-labs
axis(4)
with(df, mtext("y2", side = 4))
```

Answer (score 4):

It seemingly appears to be a simple question but it boggles around 2 fundamental questions. A) How to deal with a multi-scalar data while presenting in a comparative chart, and secondly, B) whether this can be done without some thumb rule practices of R programming such as i) melting data, ii) faceting, iii) adding another layer to existing one.
The solution given below satisfies both the above conditions as it deals data without having to rescale it and secondly, the techniques mentioned are not used.

Here is the result,
[image: better and improved]

For those interested in knowing more about this method, please follow the link below.
[How to plot a 2- y axis chart with bars side by side without re-scaling the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413787/how-to-plot-a-2-y-axis-chart-with-bars-side-by-side-without-re-scaling-the-data/54426831#54426831)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol= )` on a variable to create a new comparison.  It's not on the same axis, but it is similar.

Answer (score 1):

I acknowledge and agree with [hadley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/1053612) (and others), that separate y-scales are "fundamentally flawed". Having said that – I often wish `ggplot2` had the feature – particularly, when the data is in [wide-format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data#Wide) and I quickly want to visualise or check the data (i.e. for personal use only).

While the `tidyverse` library makes it fairly easy to convert the data to long-format (such that `facet_grid()` will work), the process is still not trivial, as seen below:

```
library(tidyverse)
df.wide %>%
    # Select only the columns you need for the plot.
    select(date, column1, column2, column3) %>%
    # Create an id column – needed in the `gather()` function.
    mutate(id = n()) %>%
    # The `gather()` function converts to long-format. 
    # In which the `type` column will contain three factors (column1, column2, column3),
    # and the `value` column will contain the respective values.
    # All the while we retain the `id` and `date` columns.
    gather(type, value, -id, -date) %>%
    # Create the plot according to your specifications
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) +
        geom_line() +
        # Create a panel for each `type` (ie. column1, column2, column3).
        # If the types have different scales, you can use the `scales="free"` option.
        facet_grid(type~., scales = "free")
```

Comment: At the time of writing ggplot2 already supported this via `sec_axis`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales/53703152#53703152) helped me the most, but found that there were some edge cases that it didn't seem to handle correctly, in particular negative cases, and also the case where my limits had 0 distance (which can happen if we are grabbing our limits from max/min of data). Testing seems to indicate that this works consistently

I use the following code. Here I assume we have [x1,x2] that we want to transform to [y1,y2]. The way I handled this was to transform [x1,x2] to [0,1] (a simple enough transformaton), then [0,1] to [y1,y2].

```
climate <- tibble(
  Month = 1:12,
  Temp = c(-4,-4,0,5,11,15,16,15,11,6,1,-3),
  Precip = c(49,36,47,41,53,65,81,89,90,84,73,55)
)
#Set the limits of each axis manually:

  ylim.prim <- c(0, 180)   # in this example, precipitation
ylim.sec <- c(-4, 18)    # in this example, temperature



  b <- diff(ylim.sec)/diff(ylim.prim)

#If all values are the same this messes up the transformation, so we need to modify it here
if(b==0){
  ylim.sec <- c(ylim.sec[1]-1, ylim.sec[2]+1)
  b <- diff(ylim.sec)/diff(ylim.prim)
}
if (is.na(b)){
  ylim.prim <- c(ylim.prim[1]-1, ylim.prim[2]+1)
  b <- diff(ylim.sec)/diff(ylim.prim)
}


ggplot(climate, aes(Month, Precip)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_line(aes(y = ylim.prim[1]+(Temp-ylim.sec[1])/b), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", sec.axis = sec_axis(~((.-ylim.prim[1]) *b  + ylim.sec[1]), name = "Temperature"), limits = ylim.prim) +
  scale_x_continuous("Month", breaks = 1:12) +
  ggtitle("Climatogram for Oslo (1961-1990)")
```

The key parts here are that we transform the secondary y axis with `~((.-ylim.prim[1]) *b  + ylim.sec[1])` and then apply the inverse to the actual values `y = ylim.prim[1]+(Temp-ylim.sec[1])/b)`. We should also ensure that `limits = ylim.prim`.

Answer (score 1):

The following incorporates [Dag Hjermann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)'s basic data and programming, improves upon [user4786271](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)'s strategy to create a "transformation function" to optimally combine the plots and data axis, and responds to [baptist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)'s note that such a function can be created within R.

```
#Climatogram for Oslo (1961-1990)
climate <- tibble(
  Month = 1:12,
  Temp = c(-4,-4,0,5,11,15,16,15,11,6,1,-3),
  Precip = c(49,36,47,41,53,65,81,89,90,84,73,55))

#y1 identifies the position, relative to the y1 axis, 
#the locations of the minimum and maximum of the y2 graph.
#Usually this will be the min and max of y1.
#y1<-(c(max(climate$Precip), 0))
#y1<-(c(150, 55))
y1<-(c(max(climate$Precip), min(climate$Precip)))

#y2 is the Minimum and maximum of the secondary axis data.
y2<-(c(max(climate$Temp), min(climate$Temp)))

#axis combines y1 and y2 into a dataframe used for regressions.
axis<-cbind(y1,y2)
axis<-data.frame(axis)

#Regression of Temperature to Precipitation:
T2P<-lm(formula = y1 ~ y2, data = axis)
T2P_summary <- summary(lm(formula = y1 ~ y2, data = axis))
T2P_summary   

#Identifies the intercept and slope of regressing Temperature to Precipitation:
T2PInt<-T2P_summary$coefficients[1, 1] 
T2PSlope<-T2P_summary$coefficients[2, 1] 


#Regression of Precipitation to Temperature:
P2T<-lm(formula = y2 ~ y1, data = axis)
P2T_summary <- summary(lm(formula = y2 ~ y1, data = axis))
P2T_summary   

#Identifies the intercept and slope of regressing Precipitation to Temperature:
P2TInt<-P2T_summary$coefficients[1, 1] 
P2TSlope<-P2T_summary$coefficients[2, 1] 


#Create Plot:
ggplot(climate, aes(Month, Precip)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_line(aes(y = T2PSlope*Temp + T2PInt), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*P2TSlope + P2TInt, name = "Temperature")) +
  scale_x_continuous("Month", breaks = 1:12) +
  theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"), 
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"), 
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red")) +
  ggtitle("Climatogram for Oslo (1961-1990)")
```

Most noteworthy is that a new "transformation function" works better with just two data points from the data set of each axes—usually the maximum and minimum values of each set. The resulting slopes and intercepts of the two regressions enable ggplot2 to exactly pair the plots of the minimums and maximums of each axis. As [user4786271](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales) pointed out, the two regressions transform each data set and plot to the other. One transforms the break points of the first y axis to the values of the second y axis. The second transforms the data of the secondary y axis to be "normalized" according to the first y axis.
The following output shows how the axis align the minimums and maximums of each dataset:

[image]

Having the maximums and minimums match may be most appropriate; however, another benefit of this method is that the plot associated with the secondary axis can be easily shifted, if desired, by altering a programming line related to the primary axis data. The output below simply changes the minimum precipitation input in the programming line of y1 to "0", and thus aligns the minimum Temperature level with the "0" Precipitation level.

From: y1<-(c(max(climate$Precip), min(climate$Precip)))

To: y1<-(c(max(climate$Precip), 0))

[image]

Notice how the resulting new regressions and ggplot2 automatically adjusted the plot and axis to correctly align the minimum Temperature to the new "base" of the "0" Precipitation level. Likewise, one is easily able to elevate the Temperature plot so that it is more obvious. The following graph is created by simply changing the above-noted line to:

"y1<-(c(150, 55))"

The above line tells the maximum of the Temperature graph to coincide with the "150" Precipitation level, and the minimum of the temperature line to coincide with the "55" Precipitation level. Again, notice how ggplot2 and the resulting new regression outputs enable the graph to maintain correct alignment with the axis.

[image]

The above may not be a desirable output; however, it is an example of how the graph can be easily manipulated and still have correct relationships between the plots and the axis.
The incorporation of [Dag Hjermann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)'s theme improves identification of the axis corresponding to the plot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[The answer by Hadley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/) gives an interesting reference to Stephen Few's report [Dual-Scaled Axes in Graphs Are They Ever the Best Solution?](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf).

I do not know what the OP means with "counts" and "rate" but a quick search gives me [Counts and Rates](http://health.utah.gov/opha/IBIShelp/compute_rate2.htm), so I get some data about Accidents in North American Mountaineering<sup>1</sup>:

```
Years<-c("1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004")
Persons.Involved<-c(281,248,301,276,295,231,311)
Fatalities<-c(20,17,24,16,34,18,35)
rate=100*Fatalities/Persons.Involved
df<-data.frame(Years=Years,Persons.Involved=Persons.Involved,Fatalities=Fatalities,rate=rate)
print(df,row.names = FALSE)

 Years Persons.Involved Fatalities      rate
  1998              281         20  7.117438
  1999              248         17  6.854839
  2000              301         24  7.973422
  2001              276         16  5.797101
  2002              295         34 11.525424
  2003              231         18  7.792208
  2004              311         35 11.254019
```

And then I tried to do the graph as Few suggested at page 7 of the aforementioned report (and following the request of OP to graph the counts as a bar chart and the rates as a line chart) :

> The other less obvious solution, which works only for time series, is
>   to convert all sets of values to a common quantitative scale by
>   displaying percentage differences between each value and a reference
>   (or index) value. For instance, select a particular point in time,
>   such as the first interval that appears in the graph, and express
>   each subsequent value as the percentage difference between it and the
>   initial value. This is done by dividing the value at each point in
>   time by the value for the initial point in time and then multiplying
>   it by 100 to convert the rate to a percentage, as illustrated below.

```
df2<-df
df2$Persons.Involved <- 100*df$Persons.Involved/df$Persons.Involved[1]
df2$rate <- 100*df$rate/df$rate[1]
plot(ggplot(df2)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=Years,weight=Persons.Involved))+
  geom_line(aes(x=Years,y=rate,group=1))+
  theme(text = element_text(size=30))
  )
```

And this is the result:
[image]

But I do not like it a lot and I am not able to easily put a legend on it...

1

<sub>WILLIAMSON, Jed, et al. *Accidents in North American Mountaineering 2005.* The Mountaineers Books, 2005.</sub>